# Full Screen Hover Signup Box -- as seen on squarespace

Tags: javascript

I love how http://www.squarespace.com/templates/?q=minsk does their signup process -- When you click on "start with this template", the entirety of the viewport is taken over, and the signup box shows up.

Does anyone know of a script that already does something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily with simple javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="trigger">Click to open</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="login">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <label>Username:
            <input type="email" name="username" />
        </label>
        <label>Password:
            <input type="password" name="pass" />
        </label>
        <button>Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay, #login {
    display: none;
}
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter:alpha(Opacity=70);
    z-index: 999;
}
/* Change styles as you like beyond here, make sure the z-index of #login be always higher than #overlay */
#login {
    position:fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #555;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#login h1 {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
#login form input {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
}
#trigger {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        $('#login').fadeIn(500);
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(500);
    });
    $('#overlay').click(function(){
        $('#login').fadeOut(500);
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

You can click the overlay to quit the window.

See the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/licson0729/R9ACe/)!

Comment: Both you and Praveen are awesome! Thank you Licson, I'm still a newb with JS, and having someone map it out for me is going to be really helpful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Modal Window**. You can achieve it using [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com) or JavaScript. For a simple start, you can check out the tutorial given by [Queness](http://www.queness.com/)'s [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

The code is very simple. First you have to build your **HTML**.

```
<!-- #dialog is the id of a DIV defined in the code below -->
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Modal Window</a>

<div id="boxes">


    <!-- #customize your modal window here -->

    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing of Modal Window</b> | 

        <!-- close button is defined as close class -->
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>

    </div>


    <!-- Do not remove div#mask, because you'll need it to fill the whole screen -->    
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Some **CSS** for the presentational look and feel.

```
/* Z-index of #mask must lower than #boxes .window */
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:fixed;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}


/* Customize your modal window here, you can add background image too */
#boxes #dialog {
  width:375px; 
  height:203px;
}
```

And finally, **JavaScript** for the interactions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});
```

You can see a **working demo** of this project hosted at [**Simple jQuery Modal Window Examples from Queness WebBlog**](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html). Click on the `Simple Window Modal` link on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while searching for a similar situation I have. I have a piece of custom javascript code that I'm using with my SS6 site. You'll have to forgive me, as I am a designer & not a developer.

Site in question:
http://tentenbtc.com

Currently, after a user clicks "Count Me In" a popup window appears that allows said user to signup. Everything works fine and all, but the popup is just a .png with some input fields & a submit button--not very elegant, and not responsive. I would like to replace the popup window with a modal that dims the background, and this thread looks like the right place to start solving my approach. Btw, the code is inline and formatted to fit into a SS codeblock.

Code for the javascript widget:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.0.19.min.js"></script>

  <style>

  .bgimg {
    background-image: url("/s/bluebk.jpg");
  }

  #overlay_form{
         position:relative;
         -moz-border-radius:4px;
         -webkit-border-radius:4px;
         border-radius:4px;
         border: 0px solid black;
         width: 640px;
         height: 340px;
         background-image: url("https://static.squarespace.com/static/532ccd30e4b00d0eac2a448c/t/533acaffe4b0cd1c8b92271c/1396361983567/tenfortenpopup.png");
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         overflow:Hidden;
         margin:0px auto;
         margin-top: -344px !important;
  }

  .slemail{
        border:0px solid white;
        font-size: 22px !important;
        width: 310px;
        height: 40px;
        font-family: "Futura-pt";
        color:#ababab;
        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
        position: absolute;
        left:    34px;
        bottom:   20px;
        -webkit-appearance : none;
        padding-left:5px;
  }

  .countertext{
       font-family: "futura-pt";
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 4px;
       color:white;
       font-size: 52.55px;
       font-weight: 700;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1;
       text-align: center;
       margin: 0px, auto;
       margin-top: 24px;
 }

  .counternumber {
       font-family: "futura-pt";
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 0px;
       color:white;
       font-size: 100.55px;
       padding:3px;
       display: inline-block;
       line-height: 100%;
       font-weight: 700;
       font-style: normal;
       background: none !important;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-top: -5px;
  }

  .hitme {
   -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
   -moz-border-radius: 45px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: solid 1px Black;
   display:inline-block;
   width: 70%;
   line-height: 1.482;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "futura-pt";
   font-size: 38.28px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: normal;
   background-color:#343e3d;
   color:white;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   margin: 0px, auto;
   margin-top: 13px;

  }

  .hitmesmall:active {  right:    38px }

  .hitmesmall {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   display:inline-block;
   width: 200px;
   padding:2px 10px;
   font-family: "futura-pt";
   font-size: 22px;
   background-color:#666666;
   color:white;
   letter-spacing:1px;
   height:41px;
   position: absolute;
   right:    40px;
   bottom:   20px;
   border: solid 0px #343e3d;    

  }

   input:focus{
     outline:none;
  }

  .exitpopup
  {
       position: absolute;
       right: 5px;
       top:   4px;
  }


</style>

<script TYPE="text/javascript"> 
  //mailchimp javascript block
  ////////////////////////////
  //Ten for Ten
      var arr = {
           apikey: "3865eadb82f9d9951067ff814b6fe34a-us4",
           id: "9f12ac9801",
     double_optin:"false",
           email:{
                  email: "replacewithemail"
               }
       }

       var url = "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json";

       function mailchimp_addemail($email)
       {

        arr.email.email = $email;

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url, 
          contentType: "application/json",
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: arr,
          complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            // alert("Mailchimp added");
          }       
       })

      return false;  
  }  
// end mailchimp javascript block
</script>




<script TYPE="text/javascript">
//popup javascript block
////////////////////////  

  function validateEmail($email) 
  {
     var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
     return re.test($email);
  }

  function openpopup()
  {

    $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(10);
    $('#subscriberemail').focus();
    $('#subscriberemail').val("your@email.com");
    just_count();
    return false;
  }

  function closepopup()
  {
     $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(10);
     return false;
  }

  function subscribe()
  {

      var $email   = $('#subscriberemail').val();
      var $checkme = $email.toLowerCase();   

      if ( validateEmail($checkme) == false)
      {
          $('#subscriberemail').val("your@email.com");
          $('#subscriberemail').focus();


          return false;
      }

      if ( $checkme == "your@email.com" ) 
      {
            $('#subscriberemail').val("your@email.com");
            $('#subscriberemail').focus();
            return false;
      }

      // kick off the parse.com stuff
      // the mailchimp call gets made on success
      parse_add($email);
      return false; 
  }
 //end popup javascript block  
</script>



<script TYPE="text/javascript">
//generic javascript block
// parse.com Appid and jskey
//////////////////////// 

  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  //Ten For Ten
  var parseappid  = "I8bjfDP5GK8UKA509BFUQAsTRmHHgocl1ppSAwDO";
  var parsejskey  = "JxvgeMDJQuHCwinZjq8TBEJmx1KUd3EwtcOmSr3e";


  var subscriber;
  var sequence;

    $( document ).ready(function() {
         Parse.initialize(parseappid, parsejskey);
         subscriber = Parse.Object.extend("subscriber");
         sequence   = Parse.Object.extend("sequence");
         // lets init the subscriber count
         parse_initcount();
    });

</script>


<script TYPE="text/javascript">
 //parse.com javascript block              
 ////////////////////////////

    function parse_addemail($email)
    {
        var addsubscriber = new subscriber();
        addsubscriber.set("email", $email);
        addsubscriber.save(null, {      
        success: function(object) {
              parse_incrementcount();
              mailchimp_addemail($email);
            },
            error: function(error) {
              alert("parse_addemail :" + error);
            }
        });
    };

    function just_count()
    {
        var query    = new Parse.Query(sequence);
        query.get("FJ2FWGWED6", {
          success: function(object)
          {
             object.increment("counter");
             object.save();
             var s = object.get("counter");
             var display = numberWithCommas(s); 
             $("#curcount").html(display);
          },
         error: function(error)
         {
           alert("parse_incrementcount :" + error);
         }
      });

   };


    function parse_incrementcount()
    {
      var query    = new Parse.Query(sequence);
      query.get("FJ2FWGWED6", {
        success: function(object)
        {


        },
       error: function(error)
       {
         alert("parse_incrementcount :" + error);
       }
    });
   };

   function parse_initcount()
    {
      var query    = new Parse.Query(sequence);
      query.get("FJ2FWGWED6", {
        success: function(object)
        {
           var s = object.get("counter");
           var display = numberWithCommas(s); 
           $("#curcount").html(display);
       },
       error: function(error)
       {
         alert("parse_initcount: " + error);
       }
    });
   };

  // this is called on from hitmesmall submit onclick
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function parse_add($email)
   {
     var query = new Parse.Query(subscriber);
     query.equalTo("email", $email);
     query.find({
        success: function(object) {

          if ( object.length == 0 )
          {
              parse_addemail($email);
        $('#subscriberemail').val("Congrats! Thanks for Pledging!");

          } else {

             $('#subscriberemail').val("Email already Subscribed !");
             $('#subscriberemail').focus();
          }

        }, error: function(error) {
           alert("parse_add: " + error);
      }

     });

  };

 //end parse.com javascript block              
</script>


</head>

  <body>
  <div class="bgimg" align=center>
    <br>
    <span class="counternumber" id="curcount">0</span>
    <br>
    <span class="countertext" id="pledged">PEOPLE HAVE PLEDGED! </span>
    <br>
    <button class="hitme" id="subscribe" onclick="return openpopup() ">COUNT ME IN!</button> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>  
  </div>

  <!-- popup form -->    
 <div id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
  <input  id="subscriberemail" class="slemail" type="text" value="your@email.com"/>
  <button id="addemail"        class="hitmesmall" onclick="return subscribe()" >SUBMIT</button>
  <button id="exitpopup"       class="exitpopup"  onclick="return closepopup()">X</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```